# How to give users access to app script managed by a GCP Project

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-cloud-platform

I have an app script linked to a spreadsheet that has a few functions to automate some processes for users. I recently updated the project to be linked to a standard GCP project I created so I could create OAuth credentials for an unrelated process in this script. However, now when users go to run the functions, they get a 403. Is there a place in the GCP console where I can give them access? I am not using any OAuth credentials for these functions. Just the standard app script interactions with the Google Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you move to GCP you are required to use OAuth and they have to enter their credentials again. Found in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project).

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the OAuth Consent Screen as is explained in the official docs about link a Google Apps Script project to a standard Google Cloud Project --> https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects

Comment: Thank you! I had configured the consent screen, but that was a little bit ago and I forgot about adding test users. I added them as test users for the application and it worked!

Comment: But how were the test users able to access it? Did they get a URL to access ?
Or you shared with them? I've added test users to my GCP of a Google Apps Script project. But how can my test users access it?

Comment: @August You have to send them the link. If you need further help, please post a new question providing more details about your specific case.

Comment: Thanks @Rubén, I got it. I've shared with the users from https://script.google.com